# Matlab principal components regression

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression, pca, princomp

i'm trying to figure out how regression using pca works in Matlab...I have standardised my variables, performed pca on them, and then done a regression on the principal components, but what is not clear to me is how I convert the regression coefficients to coefficients for my original data?!
Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the MATLAB code you have so far? Concrete code from your side will make it a lot easier to get concise answers. Otherwise the answer would almost need to be a tutorial, which is not how Stack Overflow works.